# Is there any way we can add a UIbutton on the navigation bar when the full image shows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

Is there any possibility to add a UIButton on navigation bar of the full image display in the Three20 open source.
or when the thumbs of images are displayed then the button can be added or not.

Comment: Full image means it is showing in Whole view?

Comment: means a large image of a thumbnail image

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with something like this...

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myButtonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTarget: ....];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
[barButton release];
```

Comment: but my question is that on which i add this bar button. i doesn't found anything in the api where i can add the barbutton

Comment: The actual adding happens in this line: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;` That will add it to the right on the **navigation bar**.